# .NET forms; How to access installed package from application?

Tags: .net, winforms

So I have followed instructions to download and install a package via NuGet.  It looks like it is installed and enabled for my project

[image: Package installed and checked]

But when I try to access its objects, I get an error message saying its not there.

[image]

Am I missing a step to allow me to use this namespace?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This may help: [Call UWP APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance)

Comment: Thanks!  That got me through!